# Neo4j cypher. setting reverse relationship between nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relationship

I have defined all relationships `r` with a property reverse relationship `rr`.

I am able to recover all relationship types and their `rr` with a cypher query.

Now I wish to iterate over each relation `type(r)`, get all pairs of nodes, which have this relationship. Say `(a)->[type(r)]-(b)`. Then create reverse relation ship create `(b)-[rr]->(a)` if it does not exist.

New to cypher. Unable to make headway.

please help

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking about appears to be a bad idea.

Enforcing a pattern where a relationship of some given type is *always* paired with another relationship of some given type in the opposite direction (and vice versa) is **bad practice**. This is because, with neo4j, following a relationship in either direction *is equally easy and efficient*. It is wasteful to create relationships when not necessary.

Sample **anti-patterns**:

```
(a)-[:HAS_ROOMMATE]->(b)-[:HAS_ROOMMATE]->(a)
```

and also:

```
(a)-[:HAS_HUSBAND]->(b)-[:HAS_WIFE]->(a)
```

*On the other hand, if one cannot assume that a relationship in one direction must imply some relationship in the opposite direction, then it may be OK to have relationships in opposite directions (but you should also consider the alternative of adding an appropriate flag property to a single relationship).*

By the way, when querying for a relationship, you can specify a non-directional pattern. For example, to find a `Person`'s roommate(s) you can do this (notice that the relationship pattern does not specify an arrowhead in either direction:

```
MATCH (p:Person {id: 123})-[:HAS_ROOMMATE]-(q)
RETURN p, q
```

Comment: Thanks cybersam. (a)-[:SON_OF]->(b)  has reverse relation of MOTHER_OF or FATHER_OF. I want a graph capable of making a suitable choice and setting reverse relationship. Setting such relationships could enrich it. But thanks. your comments helped clear many things.

Comment: One way to handle that kind of use case is to put a `gender` property in the `Person` node, and to use just the `CHILD_OF` relationship. That would eliminate the need for `SON_OF`, `DAUGHTER_OF`, `MOTHER_OF`, and `FATHER_OF` relationships.

Comment: Thanks cybersam. you are absolutely right. that brings the problem to next level. Inferring gender from related data, if the property has not been defined. The struggle continues!